# PowerShell import module in docker fails with error"module is not currently supported on the Core edition of PowerShell"

Tags: docker, powershell

I am trying install powercli in a php docker image so that I can publish the reports to a webpage using laravel. Powershell is installed. But PowerCLI installation is failing with the following error while importing the module. I can connect to server only when the module is imported.

```
Exception: VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView module is not currently supported on the Core edition of PowerShell.
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
.
.
.

# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Update the list of products
RUN apt-get update

# Install PowerShell
RUN apt-get install -y powershell

# Start PowerShell
#RUN pwsh

# Allow installation from PSGallery
RUN pwsh -Command 'Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted'

# Install PowerCLI, PowervRA, Vester
RUN pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -Scope CurrentUser'
RUN pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name PowervRA -Confirm:$false'
RUN pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name Vester -Confirm:$false'

# Disable CEIP warning
RUN pwsh -Command 'Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -ParticipateInCEIP $false -Confirm:$false'

# Set InvalidCertificateAction
RUN pwsh -Command 'Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false'
RUN pwsh -c 'Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI'
.
.
.
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: vapp
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./powershell/Modules/:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network
.
.
.
```

It works when manually tested on container.
Please see if anything is wrong with the dockerfile.

**UPDATE 1**
Now I have updated docker file as below:

```
# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/
RUN pwd
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    wget \
    apt-utils


RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www


# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

#########################
RUN pwd
# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Update the list of products
RUN apt-get update

# Install PowerShell
RUN apt-get install -y powershell

# Start PowerShell
#RUN pwsh

# Allow installation from PSGallery
SHELL ["pwsh", "-command"]

RUN Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
#RUN Install-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core -Confirm:$false
#RUN Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core; Get-Module

#RUN Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false
##RUN connect-viserver 10.21.24.19

RUN mkdir -p ./powershell/Modules
RUN wget https://download3.vmware.com/software/vmw-tools/powerclicore/PowerCLI_Core.zip ~/.local/share/powershell/Modules
RUN unzip -o PowerCLI_Core.zip && unzip -o 'PowerCLI.*.zip' -d ./powershell/Modules
RUN cd ./powershell/Modules
RUN pwd
RUN ls -la
RUN Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.VimAutomation.Core | Import-Module
RUN $env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ":powershell/Modules"
RUN mkdir -p /root/.config/powershell
RUN touch /root/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
RUN echo "Get-Module -ListAvailable PowerCLI* | Import-Module" >> /root/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: PowerCLI usually requires the core elements too, not just the specific module for Horizon. What happens if you just run `Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI`?

Comment: It fails with the same error. I do not need HorizonView. I was checking if ```RUN pwsh -c Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI -Function VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView ``` skips it.

Comment: ```RUN pwsh -c 'Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI -ErrorAction Continue'``` also fails

Comment: If I skip the line ```RUN pwsh -c 'Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI``` build is successful. But the commands are  not found. I feel this is because the module is not loaded. Is there a work around how I can import the modules?

Comment: The modules are installed and the error is with importing an unsupported submodule. You can edit the .psd to remove this from the load list. Look for `VMware.PowerCLI.psd1` in the install path for Powershell and edit out the module.

Comment: Found this article which should help you: https://cloudhat.eu/powercli-10-0-0-linux-error-vmware-vimautomation-srm/

Comment: Yes. I have read it. But to preserve the changes when container restarts, the comments should be made from docker file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In repsonse to your query - to do this programmatically using Powershell you could try something like this BEFORE you `Import-Module`:

```
RUN pwsh -c '(Get-Module VMware.PowerCLI -ListAvailable).RequiredModules | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView' } | Uninstall-Module'
```

Edit: Ok this won;t work.

What you could do is only import the modules you need:

```
# Generally most stuff needs the core module:
RUN pwsh -Command 'Import-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core -Scope CurrentUser'

# If for example you need to manipulate storage, also import that module
RUN pwsh -Command 'Import-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Storage -Scope CurrentUser'
```

The full list of available modules is in the VMware.PowerCLI.psd1 file. The advantage of this also is that it will be faster as you won;t be importing ALL the commands, only the ones you need to use.

Comment: Well, good idea. But it fails with error ```The module 'VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView' of version
      | '7.13.0.16985899' in module base folder
      | '/root/.local/share/powershell/Modules/VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView/7.13.0.16985899' cannot be uninstalled, because one or more other modules 'VMware.PowerCLI' are dependent on this module. Uninstall the modules that depend on this module before uninstalling module 'VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView'```

Comment: The unfortunately the hard way is to copy/edit the .psd file and rewrite it to remove the dependency before you import the module. Look up using `Get-Content` and `Out-File`

Comment: Actually, there might be another way - you don;t have to Import-Module everything, you can just import he modules you need. See my edited answer above

Comment: Yes..Thank you. yesterday I tried the same as ```RUN Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.VimAutomation.Core | Import-Module```. This answers the question. But to add to it, the install and import are not persisted meaning that connect-viserver works only while container is built but when I call it in PHP code it fails. I also tried to add to $profile ```SHELL ["pwsh", "-command"] RUN echo "Get-Module -ListAvailable PowerCLI* | Import-Module" >> /root/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1```. though it's not working. any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `Install; Module -Scope AllUsers? Anyway the only thing you need for PS module to work is for the module to be in the module path - see $PSModulePath variable for details. You don't have to Install-Module every time. You could just Install;-Module once to get the files then copy the folders/files to a known persistent location and add that location to PSModulePath.

Comment: I did not try for all users. Yeah.. I did ```RUN mkdir -p ~/.local/share/powershell/Modules
RUN wget https://download3.vmware.com/software/vmw-tools/powerclicore/PowerCLI_Core.zip
RUN unzip PowerCLI_Core.zip && unzip -o 'PowerCLI.*.zip' -d ~/.local/share/powershell/Modules```